# How to configure Linux Mint 18.2 for a Captive WiFi Access Point with no Internet Access

Tags: iptables, dnsmasq

I'm looking for help with a Linux webserver (Mint 18.2) with a WiFi Captive Access Point and NO Internet Access. When a mobile device connects to the WiFi it should automatically rerouted to the local website on this server. I'm using the `create_ap` script :

```
create_ap -n --redirect-to-localhost --isolate-clients -g 192.168.200.1 wlp3s0 MyAccessPoint
```

and php webserver (testing purpose). The mobile devices connects to the WiFi, getting an ip-adress, gateway and DNS1, but the website isn't visible automatically. If you type the ip-adress 192.168.200.1 in the browser, the site is visible. I'm using the default `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and the default iptables. I think it has to do with the automatic search for internet "http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204" when connected to the WiFi. This should be rerouted or answered with "HTTP/1.0 204 No Content" The index.html is generated from my IDE and I'm not an HTML-wizard :-(

Should I modify the dnsmasq/iptables or modify the index.html ?

Is it possible to give an example index.html which should work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i was able to do that in the past by sharing netword to a bridged router and,  dnsspoof(dnschef) complets the magic of redirecting ! (*.*.* localhost) .